# This error occurs when building a new project

Tags: flutter

> Failed to transform window-java-1.0.0-beta04.aar (androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not find window-java-1.0.0-beta04.aar (androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/window/window-java/1.0.0-beta04/window-java-1.0.0-beta04.aar

where is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding these repos to your build.gradle file and make sure you're network IP is not from A country that has been embargoed(use a vpn).

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```